# Where's Waldo-style picture book about a field trip time traveling to Ancient Egypt

Tags: interactive-fiction, identification-request

I read this book probably in the 1999-2001 range, as a library book. The text was in English; this was in the state of Ohio in the US. I don't recall the particular copy having notable wear or fading like it had been around for a long time.

The 'plot' involved a modern class of schoolkids having a field trip unintentionally land in Ancient Egypt. There were several kids in the class, along with the teacher. (There *may* have been an additional adult-ish figure along who was involved in/responsible for the time travel part, but I'm not sure of that.) The 'plot' was really just setup; the point of the book was funny art and searching the pictures for the specific things you were told to find.

The format and art was *very* similar to the Where's Waldo series--thin spine but larger-than-average pages with full spreads of dense, detailed cartoon-y art and tons of funny little bits if you took the time to look for them.

You could find all of the 'modern' characters in each spread I believe, and there was also always a silhouette of an Egyptian god or goddess hidden in each spread. I recall that in one spread, the hidden silhouette took the form of a puddle in the outline of that page's god.

The tone was a little educational--the author/artist did try to represent daily Egyptian life according to the archaeology of the day IIRC, and I think it gave little blurb descriptions for each god somewhere--but I remember it being more silly/fictional than DK-style nonfiction.

I called my childhood library for help finding the book and we ruled out the Usborne Puzzle Adventures series.

Answer (score 6):

*A Puzzling Day in the Land of the Pharaohs* by Scoular Anderson looks like a match.

From the [Publishers Weekly review](https://www.publishersweekly.com/9781564028778):

> In this flat-footed hybrid of the Magic School Bus series and the
> Waldo books, Mrs. Pudget and her students arrive at a museum to tour
> an exhibit on ancient Egypt. When the teacher pushes the wrong button
> on her audio tour cassette player, the group is transported back to
> the land of the Pharaohs, where Thoth, god of learning and magic,
> offers a tour of the Nile, the fields, a house, a temple, a pyramid,
> etc. At each location, readers are asked to find objects and people
> concealed (not very subtly) in a crowded spread; try mazes and similar
> activities; and otherwise piece together a ""puzzle"" that will enable
> the time travelers to return to the present.